# How to select the proper trait implementation in Rust?

Tags: rust, overloading, traits

I have a trait that expects either [reqwest::Response](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.22/reqwest/struct.Response.html) or [Vec](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.38.0/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html) as argument, only to throw them in a [select::document::Document](https://docs.rs/select/0.4.3/select/document/struct.Document.html). To come to that end, I need to somehow get an implementation of `io::Read` for `Vec<u8>` in order to use `Document::from_read`.

Here's what I came up with:

```rust
use select::document::Document;
use std::{io::Read, io::Result};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ReadableVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl Read for ReadableVec<u8> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        println!("Read!");
        let mut r: &[u8] = &self.0[..];
        r.read(buf)                           //< issue is here!!
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buf = ReadableVec(vec![60, 116]);
    let doc = Document::from_read(buf);
    println!("{:?}", doc)
}
```

My question is: why is `r.read(buf)` calling the `Read` implementation of `ReadableVec` instead of `&[u8]`, thus making my function to recursively call itself? The type of `r` seems very clearly instructed by the line above.

*PS: if there's a better solution to handle both `Vec<u8>` and `reqwest::Response`, it'll be appreciated in the comments! ;)*

Comment: I think [Cursor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) is the go-to way to wrap `Vec<u8>` into a `Read`-able thing

Comment: Thanks! Cursor is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can disambiguate by referencing the trait method directly, e.g.:

```rust
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ReadableVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl Read for ReadableVec<u8> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        println!("Read!");
        Read::read(&mut &self.0[..], buf)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buf = ReadableVec(vec![60, 116]);
    buf.read(&mut []);
}
```

This is called [Universal Function Call Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/ufcs.html) (can't find this chapter in the new book, so I'm linking the first edition).

I do not think this is sufficient to make the implementation of `Read` correct though, as this would only advance the (temporary) slice. See my comment on `Cursor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried that syntax too, should have mentioned it! But it still doesn't work and recurse infinitely. I find that behaviour disturbing at the very least.